# In Rails how do you change a resources routes url but keep the same url helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a simple resources route in my routes file like this:

```
resources :posts
```

I would like to change all the urls that use this to `articles`, for example `/posts/1/edit` becomes `/articles/1/edit`

Now this is as simple as changing `resources :posts` to `resources :articles`.

However what i'd like to do it keep all the posts urls in my code to that the helper method `posts_url` outputs the new url `/articles`

I've tried a few variations like the following:

```
resources :posts, to: 'articles', as: 'posts'
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all stated in the [fine guides on routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

```
resources :posts, path: 'articles'
```